# javascript type error: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I'm trying to change the value of a button from 'send' to 'sending' when it's clicked.

I get the error above called on this line:

```
document.getElementById("submin_btn").setAttribute("value","Sending...");
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing its `submit_btn` not `submin_btn`

Comment: It means there is not element with id `submin_btn`, looks like a typo `submit_btn`

Comment: I imagine you meant to type `submit_btn`. `submin_btn` probably doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem is that the element is not found.
I would double check the id and make sure the element is present at the time of calling the above line

Comment: In your browser console type `document.getElementById("submin_btn")` and see whether it is returning a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*getElementById* returns *null* if it can't find an element with the supplied ID. A more robust method (i.e. one that wont throw errors) is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit_btn"); // spelling of "submin_btn"?
if (button) button.value = "Sending...";
```

However, if the button is in a form, likely you will not see the value change in some if not most browsers. When a form submits (or navigation away from the current page begins) they cease updating the visible DOM (likely they figure "what's the point?").